# Spaces between Polylines in Osmdroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm trying to draw a track on the map (osm). But on the sharp corners apper spaces

[image]

```
String points [] = routeModel.getLatlon().split("\\|");
String [] point;
ArrayList<GeoPoint> mTrace = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : points) {
    point = s.split("-");
    GeoPoint gg = new 
    GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(point[0]),Double.parseDouble(point[1]));
    mTrace.add(gg);
}

Polyline mPolyline  = new Polyline();
mPolyline.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bonusColor));
mPolyline.setWidth(14.0f);
mPolyline.setPoints(mTrace);

mapView.getOverlays().add(polyline);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change a join configuration of a [paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) for the polyline. You may also want to change a cap configuration (that's for ends of the polyline).

For example:

```
mPolyline.getPaint().setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND)
mPolyline.getPaint().setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)
```